# Devise: I added a username field, but it's not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I've added my a username field to my `User` model, but it seems that devise isn't recognizing it when creating a new user record. I fill out the email, username and password, but I get a validation error "Username can't be blank" even though my params hash clearly has it. I don't need to have people log in with their username, but I just need them to set it when registering for a new account.

I'm using rails 4 and I've implemented the strong parameters thing mentioned on devise's github README.

Here is my `user.rb` file

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

before_save { |user| user.username = user.username.downcase }

validates_presence_of :username
validates_uniqueness_of :username, case_sensitive: false
```

Here's my `application_controller.rb` file

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :username, :password, :password) }
  end
end
```

I've also added my `registrations/new.html.erb` file:

```
<div><%= f.label :username %>
<%= f.text_field :username %></div>
```

Here's what my params hash has when I submit a new user record:

```
user: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  username: David
  email: david@example.com
  password: foobar12
  password_confirmation: foobar12
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Little remark `user.username = user.username.downcase` could be rewritten to `user.username.downcase!`

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, my strong params above was incorrect.

I fixed it by changing it to this:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
  u.permit(:email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```